# Grails and Sesame

Tags: maven, grails, gradle, sesame

I'm trying to import core libraries of OpenRDF Sesame into a Grails Application.

This is an extract of my BuildConfig.groovy file:

```
repositories {
    inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    mavenLocal()
    grailsCentral()
    mavenCentral()

}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-core:2.7.7'
}
```

I get this error message:

```
Error Could not find artifact org.openrdf.sesame:sesame-core:jar:2.7.7 in grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (scope: runtime) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

I can't figure out how to solve this issue, the artifact is available on Maven Central:
http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.openrdf.sesame%7Csesame-core%7C2.7.7%7Cpom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no jar there, just a POM file, and it has no dependencies: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/openrdf/sesame/sesame-core/2.7.7/

Looks like you're going to need to specify the individual jar dependencies that you need - e.g. http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/openrdf/sesame/sesame-http-client/2.7.7/

Comment: Thanks Burt, I solved thanks to your reply specifying the sesame-runtime dependency.